# android - setting LayoutParams to View elements programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want that the buttons had identical sizes and table was fully filled the buttons. But  the buttons have a different size, what do I wrong in?

My xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout

    </LinearLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainTableL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code:

```
layoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
mainTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainTableL);

tableRow = new TableRow[VALUE_ROWS]; 
btn = new Button[VALUE_ROWS*VALUE_COLUMNS];

for (int indexRow = 0; indexRow < VALUE_ROWS; indexRow++){
    tableRow[indexRow] = new TableRow(this); 
    tableRow[indexRow].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));


    for (int indexColumn = 0; indexColumn < VALUE_COLUMNS; indexColumn++){
        btn[countBtn] = new Button(this);
        btn[countBtn].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        btn[countBtn].setId(countBtn);
        btn[countBtn].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fon);
        tableRow[indexRow].addView(btn[countBtn],layoutParams);
        countBtn++;                 
    }
    mainTableLayout.addView(tableRow[indexRow], layoutParams);
}
```

I am sorry for my pure english.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if changing this will help you, but this definitely should be fixed. For table rows you should set `TableLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `TableRow.LayoutParams`:

```
tableRow[indexRow].setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
```

and later when you add a row, don't specify layoutParams:

```
mainTableLayout.addView(tableRow[indexRow]);
```

Also note that specifying size for rows doesn't have any effect, their width is set to `MATCH_PARENT` and the height - to `WRAP_CONTENT` (see [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)). And similar with buttons, `TableRow` sets their width to `WRAP_CONTENT` and the height - to `MATCH_PARENT` regardless of what you specify in the layout params.